# An Inequality Problem Involving Convexity

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am stuck on a problem that I want to solve for my research purposes. Here it is:

Let $p \in (0,1)$ and define $f(x) = x\log\frac{x}{p} + (1-x)\log\frac{1-x}{1-p}$ for $x \in [0,1]$. It is easy to see that $f$ is strictly convex on $[0,1]$ with a unique minimum at $x=p$.

Now, suppose that you choose any arbitrary $x_1, x_2 \in [0,1]$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$. I want to show that: $$f(x_1) + f(x_2) > 2~f\left(\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{2}}\right)~.$$

Here is what I have tried. I substituted $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = r^2$ with $r\geq 0$ and took $\theta= \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x_1}{r}\right)$. Then, in order to solve my original problem, it suffices to show that for every fixed $r > 0$ $f(r\cos\theta) + f(r\sin\theta)$ is minimzed uniquely at $\theta = \pi/4$ over the range $\theta \in \left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)~,~\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\right)$. If I take $g(\theta) = f(r\cos\theta) + f(r\sin\theta)$, then I can show that $g'(\pi/4) = 0$. Hence, the problem reduces to showing that $g$ is strictly convex over the range $\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)~,~\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\right)$. This is what I cannot show! The second derivative of $g$ becomes too ugly to handle. However, I plotted the function in MATLAB using many values of $r$, and all the plots are showing that $g$ is strictly convex.

Anyway, this is what I have tried. You can either proceed by my method, or take a different route, but I am desparate for a solution. Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The proposed inequality is false for $p \lessapprox 0.1191\ldots$. For example, at $\{p, x_1,x_2\} = \{\frac1{10}, \frac14, \frac34 \}$ the L.H.S. minus the R.H.S. $f(x_1)+ f(x_2)- 2f\left( \overline{x} \right) \approx -0.0116876635\ldots$, where $\overline{x} = \sqrt{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)\,/\,2}$ is the quadratic mean as defined in the question. For vanishingly smaller $p$, eventually the L.H.S. is smaller than the R.H.S. for most of the unit square domain $\{ x_1, x_2 \}\in [0,1]^2$

Comment: That was indeed very helpful! Can you show that my inequality holds for p>= 0.12 or for p larger than some alpha in (0,1)?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if this is still of interested to you or if you have already made more progress, but some quick and dirty numerical investigation suggest the critical p might be $(1+e^2)^{−1} \approx 0.11920292202211755594\ldots$ which seems like a reasonable expression coming out of that function.

Comment: Back in June I gave up quickly because analytically this function has a nice form but is challenging to analyze thoroughly. In light of the numerical evidence, there might be shortcuts where one can bypass some fundamental questions about the function while still address the inequality. I haven't given much thought on it, though, but just here to deliver the news.

Comment: My personal opinion is that due to bad timing (June) your question was overlooked (not enough people with the relevant analytic skills saw it). Now that this site has more active users daily (due to the fall semester), you might consider updating the post to bump it to the front page.